# AWS Python CDK: Cannot retrieve value from context provider vpc-provider

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am importing existing VPC to CDK code.

I specified `env` as discussed here. https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3082

```
MyStack(
    app,
    "airflow",
    env=core.Environment(account="98765432", region="ap-southeast-1")
)
```

Then used `from_lookup`.

```
from aws_cdk import aws_ec2
class MyStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, app: core.App, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(app, id, **kwargs)
        vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "vpc", vpc_id="vpc-xxx")
```

but I still got this error. Am I missing something?

> jsii.errors.JSIIError: Cannot retrieve value from context provider vpc-provider since account/region are not specified at the stack level. Either configure "env" with explicit account and region when you define your stack, or use the environment variables "CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT" and "CDK_DEFAULT_REGION" to inherit environment information from the CLI (not recommended for production stacks)

Comment: You should pass the MyStack's constructor arguments to the base class ctor, like
`class MyStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, app: core.App, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(app, id, **kwargs)
        vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "vpc", vpc_id="vpc-xxx")`

But anyway seems vpc from lookup does not work these days in aws cdk python.

Comment: Yes I did it. updated the code above. also reported this issue. https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9477

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working for you but when I put the same code into an application on my machine it is working for me.

Comment: Did you actually import the VPC? Can you show your `cdk synth`?

Comment: PytestStack(app, "pytest",env=core.Environment(account="12", region="us-west-2"))

why i am not even able to run it? i get error takes 3 positional arguments but 4 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but replacing the env parameter with this made it work for me:

```
env={
    'account': "<account-id>",
    'region': "<region>"
}
```

The full code sample would be:

**Creating the stack:**

```
MyStack(
    app,
    "airflow",
    env={
        'account': "<account-id>",
        'region': "<region>"
    }
)
```

**Stack code:**

```
from aws_cdk import aws_ec2
class MyStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, app: core.App, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(app, id, **kwargs)
        vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "vpc", vpc_id="vpc-xxx")
```

Seems to be expected behaviour for versions >= 0.36.0 as discussed in this comment:

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3082#issuecomment-507055897

In my case it worked when using the ec2.Vpc.from_lookup